# Compute distance for each element of two big lists in Python

Tags: python, geolocation

I have two big lists of tuples (size > 5000) that contains coordinates like this:

```
l1 = [ (33.5779, -111.925),
 (33.5738, -111.906),
 (33.5556, -111.899),
...
 (33.5646, -111.915),
 (33.5733, -111.863)]

l2 = [ (33.4318, -111.938),
 (33.5228, -111.9),
 (33.5387, -111.885),
...
 (33.5264, -111.925),
 (33.538, -111.888)]
```

I would like to find what are the combination that respect the following condition:

```
distance <= arbitraryDistance
```

where distance is:

```
 from geopy.distance import great_circle
 great_circle((longitude1,latitude1), (longitude2,latitude2))
```

What is the fastest way to do that?

Comment: Just to make clarity of your question, you want to pick a point from list one and points from list two such that their distance is less than or equal to some value?

Comment: Exactly, I want to find all the combinations of points where the distance between these two points is less or equal to "arbitraryDistance"

Comment: I am going to link this here; I believe this will be the fastest way to solve your answer - and certainly faster than comparing every element against the other.  Since I am not really giving code snippets, but pointing you in the right direction, I will just leave it in the comments here.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm

Comment: I haven't find any good implementation of this sweep line algorithm which seems quite complex and my time is quite limited but thanks for the idea :)

Answer (score 2):

A solution that I have found and which is relatively fast is to use the function [cdist](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) from scipy.spatial.distance

It computes the euclidean distance between every combination of points from two lists. Even though it does not computes the distance in meters, but in degrees I can still convert my meter requirement to degrees.

So my current solution looks like this:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
l1 = [ (33.5779, -111.925),
 (33.5738, -111.906),
 (33.5556, -111.899),
...
 (33.5646, -111.915),
 (33.5733, -111.863)]

l2 = [ (33.4318, -111.938),
 (33.5228, -111.9),
 (33.5387, -111.885),
...
 (33.5264, -111.925),
 (33.538, -111.888)]

distanceRequired = 0.02 #arbitrary number in degrees

matrixOfDistances = cdist(l1,l2)
for index1,value1 in enumerate(matrixOfDistances):
  isABusinessOpportunity = True
  for index2,value2 in enumerate(value1):
    if value2 <= distanceRequired:
      isABusinessOpportunity = False
        break

  if isABusinessOpportunity:
    print "The combination is:" + str(index1) + str(index2)
```

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that list comprehension would work great here

```
Result = []
Result = [great_circle(x,y) for x in l1 for y in l2 if great_circle(x,y) <= ArbitraryDist]

print(Result)
```

Try this

Comment: This solution works but it's really slow. For comparing two lists of ~5000 items it can takes up to 30s, which is too long for me

Answer (score 0):

There are two enterprettations of your answer, I will answer both.

**Either you want the distance of element 1 in list one and element 2 in list two:**

I would do this using [Geopandas](http://geopandas.org/user.html) which is a mashup of [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) and [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html). Shapely is a lot like geopy, and pandas is a mathematical library for doing vectorized calculations. Your problem suits itself very well to being vectorized and you can gain some really good speedups due to that fact.

The distance between two points in Shapely can be calculated like this:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point

Point(1,1).distance(Point(4,3))
3.605551275463989
```

Create two `GeoSeries` out of your two lists where every tuple of x, y should be a Shapely Point.

You can then use the native `GeoSeries.distance` method which takes your other `GeoSeries` and returns a list of distances.

```
from geopandas import GeoSeries

s1 = GeoSeries([Point(1,1), Point(2,1)])
s2 = GeoSeries([Point(4,3), Point(2,5)])

s1.distance(s2)
0    3.605551
1    4.000000
dtype: float64
```

With this `GeoSeries` of distances you can simply say

```
gs_dist = s1.distance(s2)
mask = gs_dist < 4
```

and you will receive a list of `True` / `False` for which ones match the condition.

You can slice into your GeoSeries with this mask, like this:

```
s1[mask]
0    POINT (1 1)
dtype: object
```

**Or you want the distance between each and all elements in both lists**

As combinations of two lists of 5000 objects will tend to explode in memory, you probably want to use a generator.

[itertools](http://geopandas.org/user.html) has a good generator for combinations.

Use [itertools.izip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) to get all possible pairs of all elements in a generator way:

```
for pair in itertools.izip(l1, l2):
   point1, point2 = pair
   distance = point1.distance(point2)
```

Comment: I wasn't able to install geopandas with pip (many errors during the installation) so I couldn't try this solution :/

Comment: pip install geopandas [...]
     Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_michael/rtree
Full code here: http://pastebin.com/PhANgM15

Comment: Second line of your pastebin says it is already installed, but an old beta version. use --upgrade

Comment: Thank you a lot, I was able to install geopandas :) However I get a "AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute 'distance'" when I run gs1.distance(gs2). http://pastebin.com/482kF9mq Is there something wrong my GeoSeries ?

Comment: It seems I confused geopy and shapely. I updated my answer, hope it still is helpful.

Comment: Thank you, it works however it computes the distances between s1[i] and s2[i]. My goal is that for s1[i] it will compute the distances to every element of s2 (so distance(s1[i], s2[0] and distance(s1[i], s2[1]) and etc...

Comment: @firelynx I don't think `izip` is what he wants. [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) sounds like the right thing